# JAVA Traversing json object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've this JSON object (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4947388/raw/9efc07f1ac8442c459cf3c6c912d953e2efc6949/stackoverflow.json) which I want to traverse and access the values of particular keys like streetAdress or surname and store them as string. I want to do this in Java using either JSON Object or jackson, any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String JSON_DATA;

String streetAddress = "";
String surname       = "";

int tempPos = JSON_DATA.indexOf("StreetAddress");
streetAddress = JSON_DATA.substring(tempPos+14)
int deliminator = streetAddress.indexOf(",");
streetAddress = streetAddress.substring(0,deliminator);
```

Now streetAddress has the value of Street address in it

Now do the same for surname

Comment: Its implied by the way that string JSON_DATA has the Json string in it.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the key is "d" and everything else is value. So, will indexof still work?

Comment: In this case yes but only because indexOf grabs the first instance of the letter

Comment: You can also use "{ \"d\" ;" as your value for indexOf

Comment: One trick that I like to use is create a string called temp and stick ALL the data in there. THEN you grab the data that you want from top to bottom. As you grab it you delete it from temp and then grab the next

Comment: ok thanks, is there no easy way to achieve this? As I've to access nearly all the values.

Comment: The easiest way I know is to use the key values as an index in the string and parse it apart. It gives you full control and the ability to modify your results very accuratley. It takes a little work to get the hang of it but you will see the power of doing it this way after a couple tries.